# Finding unit vector perpendicular to plane of another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine the unit vector perpendicular to the plane of vector A = 2i-6j-3k and vector B = 4i+3j-k

Answer (score 2):

Take the vector product $(2,-6,-3) \times (4,3,-1)$ to get a perpendicular vector then divide it by it's norm to obtain a unit vector.